# Why is this exception being thrown? Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, babeljs

```
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router'
import App from './App'
import Home from './Home'
import Repos from './Repos'
import Repo from './Repo'
import About from './About'

module.exports = (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
            <Route path="/repos/:userName/:repoName" component={Repo} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
)
```

I didn't expect to have to import React here. Of course, the fix is easy. I just need to add the following:

```
import React from 'react'
```

What is puzzling to me is that React is not explicitly used in the code sample I pasted above. I guess it is being required when the Babel/JSX code is transpiled to JavaScript?

Could you tell me exactly why am I required to import React here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, the code transpiled by Babel will use `React`.

You can check for yourself using the ["try it out" feature of the Babel website](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=module.exports%20%3D%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoute%20path%3D%22%2F%22%20component%3D%7BApp%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CIndexRoute%20component%3D%7BHome%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoute%20path%3D%22%2Frepos%22%20component%3D%7BRepos%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoute%20path%3D%22%2Frepos%2F%3AuserName%2F%3ArepoName%22%20component%3D%7BRepo%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoute%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoute%20path%3D%22%2Fabout%22%20component%3D%7BAbout%7D%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoute%3E%0A)) to see what your code will be transpiled to.

In your case, you'll get

```
"use strict";

module.exports = React.createElement(
    Route,
    { path: "/", component: App },
    React.createElement(IndexRoute, { component: Home }),
    React.createElement(
        Route,
        { path: "/repos", component: Repos },
        React.createElement(Route, { path: "/repos/:userName/:repoName", component: Repo })
    ),
    React.createElement(Route, { path: "/about", component: About })
);
```

As you can see, `React.createElement` is called multiple times.